# Can you add shortcode as a menu item link?

Tags: menus, shortcode

I want to use the Ninja Forms pop-up modal from a link in my menu. I used this plugin to make shortcodes work in the menu but couldn't get it to work: https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-in-menus/

Is there a way to do it?

When I inspect the code it the link is: `<a href="#ninja-forms-modal-1" rel="nf-modal:open" class="nf-modal-link">Click here to fill out out form</a>` Is there a way to skip the shortcode and just add that?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the Shortcode in Menu; but Menu Walker Class is your best bet to achieve what you want. Walker Class will pass on each Menu element to your code, this is where you can catch your menu item and make the desired modal pop-up link for `a href` of your menu item.

For more information on Walker class, see this link:
[Class Reference/Walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)